# Angular 2: How to preserve class methods on deserialization?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

Let's say I have a class `Foo`:

```
export class Foo {
    name: string;

    printName(): void {
        console.log(this.name);
    } 
}
```

Now the problem is that when my `FooService` gets a `Foo` from my backend as JSON and creates a Foo object out of it, it doesn't have `printName()` because there's no such thing in the JSON object.

How should I arrange this (in the context of Angular 2)? Do I have to create my methods outside the class so that they just take a `Foo` as an argument?

In Java, for example, it's perfectly fine that DTO's have methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store a javascript function in JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517173/how-to-store-a-javascript-function-in-json)

Comment: What is your goal? I didn't get it. Do you want to execute your printName() mehtod on your Foo object, like this.foo.printName() ?

Comment: I might have some more complex methods that computes something from the data fields, for example. I guess it's completely normal that a class have some methods? This is not a struct.

Comment: So, some external entity wants to call Foo's methods after they have been fetched from the server.

Comment: @YounesM This is actually the opposite. Deserializing the class from JSON "deletes" the methods.

Comment: JSON cannot have functions. So you cannot "serialize" your class into a JSON

Comment: @YounesM That's why I asked how I should arrange this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually you only transfer an object with the values over http not a class instance. You have to **create the class instance yourself**.

```js
export class Foo {

    constructor(name: string) {}
    printName(): void {
        console.log(this.name);
    } 
}


// data deserialized by angular from the request
let data = { name: 'John' };

let foo: Foo = new Foo(data.name);
```

If it helps you can make interfaces for the data you receive from the server and pass that to the constructor of the Foo class.

Note: keep in mind that there is no type casting in TS. 
If you are doing something like

```
let foo: Foo = <Foo> data;
```

It is a type assertion, you just tell the compiler that **data** is of type **Foo** it doesn't do anything to the **data** object.

Comment: yes, it serializes/deserializes stuff to an object, not a class instance. You might be confusing type assertion for type casting. :)