# Convert JavaScript code to literal String in Python

Tags: javascript, python, json

What I need to do is parse some data in `JavaScript` to `JSON`. In my data I have some fields (e.g. functions) that can't be formatted to `JSON`. That is why I want to convert it to something like raw data/literal string. As far as I know this should help me iterate over it and add the proper things to a dictionary (or ommit some data like functions) so I can parse it to `JSON` easily later. Is there a proper way to do that? Or Am I missing something? Maybe I cannot do that? I'm working in `Python`. This is sample JavaScript code:

```
MyObject.data('container', {
    animal: {
        type: 'big'
    },
    name: {
        shortname: 'jerry'
    },
    additionalData: {
        text: 'Source: <a href="example.com">' +
            'example.com</a>'
    },
    moreData: {
        numebrofLegs: 4,
        someFuncion: {
            datadata: function () {
                return this.name; // some comment
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Check this out and see if it helps you solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517173/how-to-store-a-javascript-function-in-json

Comment: This is not the problem, I want just ommit the function and store the rest in the json