# Meteor - "Unexpected token import" when using new Function() with "import"

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to read a file from ipfs/internet and then execute it in a meteor-environment. As one cannot place functions in a json-file, I thought I'd try [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47558227/2746742) where the function code is separated in two string fields and then put togheter with `new Function(arguments, body)`.

The problem I've encountered is that this...

> new Function("message, signedMessage", 'import {elliptic} from
>   "elliptic";')

creates this...

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

That is, javascript doesn't seem to be able to read Meteor-specific (?) code such as `import`. It works fine with the node-notation `const elliptic = require("elliptic");`.

Is it possible to use `new Function()` to accept code with `import`-notation into the meteor framework?

Also, any suggestions on how to solve my main problem (getting code from the net into the meteor framework) is appreciated. :-)

Comment: The `import` syntax can only appear at the outer lexical level of the code, not inside functions. (Except for "dynamic" imports, which the above code isn't doing.)

Comment: @Pointy and in Node.js, you can only use `import` by enabling experiment features

Comment: `Also, any suggestions on how to solve my main problem` how much of this foreign code is really required to be injected into your app? Can you please elaborate a bit more on your overall setup?

Comment: Strangely enough, I have been able to put these kinds of static imports in any function in my meteor projects - even when I've never placed them in their regular place. Maybe some meteor magic?

But thanks for the pointer, @Pointy! I'm looking for a new workaround now.

Comment: @Jankapunkt, What I want to do is run external code and see if it executes in a certain way. So, let's say we have a `HelloWorld`-greeter with publicKey-controlled access. I want to run it with some external input and see what the results are.

Comment: In you Meteor project `import` works, because Meteor builds your code before running and transpiles all the imports down to a node/browser compatible module structure.