# How to convert String to Function prototype in JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a js object with the following sample key-value pairs.

```
var serial = { 
 open: function(a, b) { 
       do something..
},

close: function (a,b) { 
       do something
}

}
```

As seen above the value for the keys are js functions. Due to some requirements I had to convert the whole object to string. I had used the following code to convert it to string:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(window.serial, function(key, value) {
    if (typeof value === 'function') {
        return value.toString();
    } else {
        return value;
    }   
});
```

How can I convert the strings back to function prototypes and store it in the same obj?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem: why do you ever need to store a function as a string?

Comment: @Terry Its due to some requirements/complexities

Comment: Sounds like an odd requirement. Normally, you'd just send the *data*, no functions or methods, and then initialise an object using the data. The object knows about the methods it needs.

Comment: [you have a similar question posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517173/how-to-store-a-javascript-function-in-json)

Comment: What exactly is "*do something*"? Can the function (closure) even be properly represented as a string?

Comment: @Bergi Its been converted to a string without any problem. Its just that I need to convert it back to a Function

Comment: @krishnanspace `return ""` also converts the function to a string without any problem. But a string that cannot be converted back to a function actually doing what you want. It could, again, trivially be converted to the empty function of course.

Answer (score -1):

`eval` will convert string back to function

```js
var str = "function fn(){ console.log('loggin function') }";

eval(str);

fn();
```

Comment: `eval()` should almost never be used.

Comment: @Utkanos Actually, `eval` is the sensible choice to convert a string to executable code.

Comment: @Bergi I agree with you. However, the thing is that most times I've not seen a *sensible* reason to transfer functions as strings. A lot of times it's an XY problem that somebody is trying to solve and has decided "Hey, I can turn this to a string" when there are better alternatives. However, that's not to say there *aren't* times you'd want to convert text into executable code. You can serialise functionality and send push it over a websocket, so it gets executed on a different machine, for example. It's a simple and effective way to get distributed computation going.