# JSON stringify skip nested object which has more than 3 levels

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, json-serialization, object-serialization

I wanted to store the object in local storage and I serialized the object using JSON.stringify. Then some of the inner attributes are missing after parse using JSON.parse.

I attached 2 images below to see the changes and appreciate it if anyone can answer a better solution for this. Thanks.

***This object is just before stringified using JSON***.

[image]

***This object is stringified and parse using JSON***

[image]

This is how i store and retreive data

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you just use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`? Can you show us how you stringify and parse please

Comment: functions are not valid values in JSON. When you stringify, `difficulty` and other function keys are ignored

Comment: ohh then what is the solution to store the whole JSON object in local storage?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store a javascript function in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517173/how-to-store-a-javascript-function-in-json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Json.Stringify does not pass functions into the stringified JSON, i.e. functions will not be copied into the string as functions are not valid JSON objects. In your case, the difficulty is a function and as such won't be copied.

You can include the function by using a replacer:

```js
JSON.stringify({
   /* your object here */
}, function(key, val) {
        return (typeof val === 'function') ? '' + val : val;
});
```

Comment: Do u know how to parse the stringified functions?

Comment: You can use the javascript `eval` function and a custom reviver. You can read more about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517173/how-to-store-a-javascript-function-in-json