# import json file that contains a function using javascript with webpack

Tags: json, webpack

From what I understand the json specification has first calss support for methods/functions.

I have the following json file that I am using as a test fixture.

```json
{
  "tokenParsed": {
    "preferred_username": "Test User"
  },
  "hasResourceRole": function () {
    return function (role, resource) {
      if (role && resource) {
        return true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I try to import the file into my VueJS project with

```
import { keycloak_test_user } from './fixtures/keycloak_test_user.json'
```

I get the following error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( in JSON at position 89
        at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

      2 | import Vuex from 'vuex'
      3 | import Permission from '@/components/user/Permission.vue'
    > 4 | import { keycloak_test_user } from './fixtures/keycloak_test_user.json'
```

The above json works fine if I add it directly in my test file rather than importing it.

Although, the error says JSON.parse, I am not sure if that is because webpack is not laoding the file correctly or if JSON.parse is a direct cause for the error, however, even VSCode json formatting sees the function as invalid json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can't store functions in json. There are ways to do it but that does not mean it is a good idea. Check [the accepted answer in this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517173/how-to-store-a-javascript-function-in-json) for a possible solution. I would not recommend doing it though and ask yourself why you need to store the function in the first place and if there is a better solution for your problem.

Comment: Because Keycloak returns help functions in the json object it returns when you login and the code I am testing relies on these methods and functions. JSON has first class support for methods/functions

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by replacing my `.json` file with a `.js` file like so

```
  const keycloak = {
    tokenParsed: {
      preferred_username: "Test User"
    },
    hasResourceRole: () => {
      return (role, resource) => {
        if (role && resource) {
          return true
        }
      }
    }
  }

  export default keycloak
```

I can then import as normal with

```
import keycloak from './fixtures/keycloak_test_user'
```