# Create date information in the file structure in the JSON file

Tags: json, date, structure

is it possible to specify a date in the JSON structure, like for example in PHP (https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.date.php):

```
$my_date = date("m.d.Y");
```

What I mean, here is an example of the JSON file:

```
{
    "dates_set_1":"test-1",
    "my_date":date("m.d.Y")
}
```

Is it possible to specify a date like this?
And if so, how?

Comment: answers on the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517173/how-to-store-a-javascript-function-in-json) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it. Like this

> date("F j, Y, g:i a");                 // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm